# Magento custom item and default.phtml for email

Tags: magento

I'm trying to make a custom email template, but I don't want to change these files since they are used when sending order confirmations to customers. I'm in need of a seperate template that should be send as notifications to us, when an order goes through (Doing this by an extension). But I'am unsure on how to handle this? I'm having trouble finding any usable guides on the subject.

---

> **The code that is loading the SKU/QTY I need**
>     {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
>  
>    **The files that I think is used by this code:**
>      ../default/store/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
>      ../default/store/template/email/order/items.phtml

Or would there be a more direct, and maby easier approach to get the sku/qty which is what I need.(pr. orderline).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a new layout handle to your theme's layout.  I'd suggest duplicating `sales_email_order_items` section from `sales.xml`.

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_email_order_items>
```

Below this copy and paste the following:

```
<admin_sales_email_order_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/admin/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/admin/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/admin/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</admin_sales_email_order_items>
```

In the transactional email which goes to admin you need to change `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}` to `{{layout handle="admin_email_order_items" order=$order}}`

Comment: This should make perfectly sense. But I'm not sadly not getting any results, I've been looking through it all and cannot find any problems with it..

Comment: is this issue solved?? I need answer on how to solve this.. facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

**Change line of code in above solution of 'Adam Paterson'**

```
<admin_sales_email_order_items> and </admin_sales_email_order_items>
```

to

```
<sales_email_admin_order_items> and </sales_email_admin_order_items>
```

**In the transnational email which goes to admin you need to change**

***app/locale/en_US/template/youradminnotificationemailtemplatename.html***

```
 {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

to

```
 {{layout handle="sales_email_admin_order_items" order=$order}}
```

Create a folder "admin" under email folder in your theme and copy paste order folder inside admin folder.

Now you can edit ***sales/admin/order/items/order/default.phtml*** file according to your need.